# This JQuery code to toggle a div doesn't work in IE7, but works in other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jquery, jquery-chaining

Here's my problem, I have a piece of jquery that works fine in modern browsers, but won't work in IE7.

The idea is when you click on one of the < A > tags, the div called "innerdetails" will open.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul class="table">
<li><a href="#">CLICK HERE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Techniques</a> </li>
<li >3</li>
<div class="innerdetails">
   Technical services, including MARC.
</div>
</ul>
```

Here's the offending Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.table li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").children(".innerdetails").toggle();
    alert ( $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").children(".innerdetails").length )
    return false;
    });
});
```

The interesting thing is that in the alert, IE7 returns "0" as length for .children(".inner-course-details")

Chrome returns "1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely due to the fact that this isn't valid HTML (a `ul` tag can't contain a `div` tag), so IE7 probably doesn't consider it part of the DOM tree.

To fix, try putting the `div` inside of an `li` tag (or just using an `li` tag instead), then `.toggle()`ing the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why but if you change the `children` to `find` it works

```
$("ul.table li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").find(".innerdetails").toggle();
    alert ( $(this).parent("li").parent("ul").find(".innerdetails").length )
    return false;
});
```

And the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6heVt/2/